# Error while starting zookeeper with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

While running Zookeeper with Kafka on windows 10 I am getting below error :

```
kafka_2.12-2.4.1>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Please advice on how can this be solved.

P.S : I am using JDK - 1.8.0_181.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your Kafka distribution somewhere else, so you don't have very long path to that directory + `bin\windows\...`

IMHO, on Windows it's better to use Kafka in the Docker images, than try to run it natively - Windows has a lot of restrictions, compared to Linux/Unix that are primary platforms for running Kafka & other big data applications.